# Что такое дроплет на хостинге?

Tags: hosting

Объясните что это значит? Где мне поближе об этом почитать

Answer (score 2):

Облачный провайдер DigitalOcean называет [дроплетами](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/) (каплями) свои виртуальные машины на Linux.

Каждый дроплет представляет из себя отдельный виртуальный частный сервер, DigitalOcean предоставляет возможности управления дроплетами.

Почитать об этом можно в справке на сайте DigitalOcean. Нашел еще такую статью: [DigitalOcean: знакомство — Droplet, Floating IP, Firewall](https://rtfm.co.ua/digitalocean-znakomstvo-droplet-floating-ip-firewall/). Плюс к этому в отдельных уроках по разработке приложений используется Digital Ocean.